# How to install x86 architecture for java using Ansible

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I'm doing something like:
`dpkg --add-architecture i386` using command module in Ansible. But I want to use Ansible core module to achieve it.

apt module has a parameter "dpkg_options". But I haven't had any success installing this package.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
# 32-bit dependencies for Android binaries
- lineinfile: dest=/var/lib/dpkg/arch line="amd64" create=yes
- lineinfile: dest=/var/lib/dpkg/arch line="i386" create=yes
  register: add_i386
- apt: name={{item}} update_cache={{add_i386.changed}}
  with_items: ['libc6:i386', 'libstdc++6:i386', 'zlib1g:i386']
```